# How to restrain user to one checkbuttons checked tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a GUI with several checkbuttons (the number of checkbuttons is random it depends on the file that the user put in parameter before).

And so i would like to know if it's possible to restrain the user to one checkbuttons checked at once.

I know i can create radiobuttons but the fact is i have same variable and same value for radiobuttons and when i use radiobuttons i can check both buttons and i can't uncheck them. Here is my code :

```
for element in self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams:
    diagramVar = IntVar()
    diagram = Radiobutton(self.window, text=element, variable=diagramVar, value=1)
    diagram.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)

    self.diagramVars[self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams.get(element)] = diagramVar

self.validate = Button(self.window, text="Validate", command=self.validateCallBack, width=15, height=3)
self.validate.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)
```

I have a code which works with checkbuttons but i don't know how to restrain to one checked.

Thanks for helping !

Edit : This is what it looks like, value are ok but both are checked and i can't unchecked them i though radiobuttons was when i check one the other one is unchecked.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKJt8.png

Image 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOnNV.png

Comment: A group of Radiobuttons must share the same variable for them to work right (and be given distinct `value=` options, so you can tell which one was selected).

Comment: Radiobuttons are specifically designed to give the user the ability to make a single choice from a group. From a usability point of view, using a checkbutton would be confusing to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: I know i can create radiobuttons but the fact is i have same variable
>   and same value for radiobuttons and when i use radiobuttons i can
>   check both buttons and i can't uncheck them.

`Radiobuttons` work a bit differently to `Checkbuttons`. With radio buttons, you can create "groups" where only one of the group can be selected. The way you do this is have all the `Radiobuttons` to use the same `IntVar()` as their `variable=` field, and then have each `Radiobutton` have a different value.

You can do this in a loop by using an `enumerate for loop`, like so:

```
diagramVars = {}
diagramVar = IntVar()

for i, element in enumerate(self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams):
    diagram = Radiobutton(self.window, text=element, variable=diagramVar, value=i)
    diagram.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)

    self.diagramVars[self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams.get(element)] = diagramVar

self.validate = Button(self.window, text="Validate", command=self.validateCallBack, width=15, height=3)
self.validate.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)
```

For this you wouldn't need a dictionary, since the value of the IntVar will be the RadioButton which is selected.

E.g. If `Radiobutton` #1 is selected, then the `diagramVar.get()` will return 0, If `Radiobutton` #2 is selected, then the `diagramVar.get()` will return 1, etc. This is because the groups of radio buttons need the same `IntVar()`

Comment: Thanks but i have the same weird problem. when i run my app one of the radiobuttons is already selected and if i check another one they both stay checked and i can't unselect them

Comment: I edit the original post with a screenshot of what it looks like

Comment: @Lucas oh sorry yes, I accidentally forgot to remove a line of code, I still had diagramVar being defined on the inside, it should work now.

Comment: Before your answer i tried this and it solve the problem of both slected but now both variable are equals (i put the screenshot at the end of my original post !)

Comment: @Lucas I explained this in my answer. This is because the radioButtons now share the same IntVar() variable, and so now the intVar represents which radioButton is pressed, not whether the radio button itself is pressed.

Comment: there is no possibility with radiobuttons to have 0 for all radiobuttons unchecked and `i` for radiobutton which is selected ?

Comment: It's ok thanks ! as i said  i will try to do : `if diagramVar.get() = 1 so i pick the data of the element 1 in the dictionnary`