# My radiobuttons stay checked after select them and can't unselect them python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have a GUI with as many radiobuttons as there is element in a dictionary. When i run the app :

step 1) all of them are unselected and value equal to 0 (all good)

step 2) i select one his value is equal to its position in the dictionary (second element = 2)

step 3) and when i select an other radiobuttons both stay selected and both value are like 2 and 3 if it's second and third element

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKJt8.png

Here is my code :

```
for i, element in enumerate(self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams, start=1):
    diagramVar = IntVar(value=0)
    diagram = Radiobutton(self.window, text=element, variable=diagramVar, value=i)
    diagram.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)

self.validate = Button(self.window, text="Validate", command=self.validateCallBack, width=15, height=3)
            self.validate.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)
```

I don't get why all radiobuttons stay selected when I check them. The goal of radiobuttons isn't that only one can be selected?

Thanks for helping !

Edit with `diagramVar`outside the loop :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE4mm.png

Comment: Try to move the creation of `diagramVar` outside the for loop.

Comment: I tried this and now when i check one the variable of all checkbuttons are equal (edited my post with the screenshot)

Comment: @Lucas I explained this in my answer to the previous, duplicate question you posted. This is because the `radioButtons` now share the same `IntVar()` variable, and so now the intVar represents which radioButton is pressed, not whether the radio button itself is pressed.

Comment: @Lucas For example, if radiobutton #1 is pressed then the IntVar returns 0, if radiobutton 2 is pressed, then the IntVar return 1, if radiobutton 3 is pressed, then the IntVar return 2, so on so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, [like in my last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259937/how-to-restrain-user-to-one-checkbuttons-checked-tkinter-python), you move the `diagramVar` to the outside of the loop, and now to get which `Radiobutton` is selected you can just use `diagramVar.get()` and the number will represent which `Radiobutton` is selected.

```py
diagramVar = IntVar(value=0)

for i, element in enumerate(self.listdiagram.dict_diagrams, start=1):
    diagram = Radiobutton(self.window, text=element, variable=diagramVar, value=i)
    diagram.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)

self.validate = Button(self.window, text="Validate", command=self.validateCallBack, width=15, height=3)
            self.validate.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1)

# Getting which radiobutton is selected
def getRadioSelect():
    return diagramVar.get() # the number returned will now represent which radiobutton is selected.
```

E.g. If `Radiobutton` #1 is selected, then the `diagramVar.get()` will return 0, If `Radiobutton` #2 is selected, then the `diagramVar.get()` will return 1, etc. This is because the groups of `Radiobuttons` need the same `IntVar()`

Comment: Ok thanks i will try to do : `if diagramVar.get() = 1 so i pick the data of the element 1 in the dictionnary`

Comment: What do you mean by "like in my last alswer"? What "last answer" are you referring to?